# Docusign Webhooks

Tags: python-3.x, docusignapi, webhooks, hmacsha1

I implemented DocuSign webhooks using ngrok, but the notification takes about **20-25 seconds** to hit the application API. Can anyone please verify is this the normal time that it takes to send a notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is normal.
Especially in the Developer Environment (demo, formally known as the "sandbox").
In production this time is shorter and it's faster to get the notification into your webhook.